# libCEC fails to turn on my Philips av receiver

Tags: pi-2, kodi

Here is my configuration

```
Raspberry Pi2B(openelec 5/6) -> Receiver -> TV
```

The issue is that my av receiver (Philips/HTB5150KD) appears like it does not get turned on or standby via KODI(libCEC). TV turns on/standby successfully. I have tried libCEC setting to turn on TV/AVR, but still failed to turn on receiver.

Strange part is that receiver responds commands from TV (if I enable setting to standby all devices in CEC menu, my receiver goes to standby when I put TV to standby). Remote control is passed to KODI. It appears in CEC menu.
is not responding to "on" command from libCEC. I have configured my receiver to play the audio(no ARC), volume is properly controlled on receiver.

I have also tried to send commands manually but still receiver fails to turn on.
Here is my diagnosis

Device list:

```
OpenELEC:~ # echo lad | cec-client -s -d 1
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
listing active devices:
logical address 0
logical address 1
logical address 4
logical address 5
```

TV stats:

```
OpenELEC:~ # echo ven 0 | cec-client -s -d 1
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
vendor id: 0000f0
OpenELEC:~ # echo pow 0 | cec-client -s -d 1
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
power status: on
```

Receiver stats:

```
OpenELEC:~ # echo ven  5 | cec-client -s -d 1
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
vendor id: 000000
OpenELEC:~ # echo pow 5 | cec-client -s -d 1
opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
power status: unknown
```

here is full debug while trying to power on receiver http://pastebin.com/aF5kPHii

I believe the issue is caused due to some vendor specific implementation missing in libCEC.

Are you able to put some light on this issue and provide any possible workaround (if any)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried configuring your AV-Receiver?

I found the following manual: [Philips/HTB5150KD manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/664690/Philips-Htb5150kd.html?page=15#manual)

Enable EasyLink:

1. Press (Home).
2. Select [Setup], and then press OK.
3. Select [EasyLink] > [EasyLink] > [On] .
4. On your TV and other connected devices, turn on HDMI-CEC control. For details, see the user manual of the TV or other devices.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. Yes, Easy link(CEC) is turned on for my receiver and Audio control has been enabled. Anynet(Samsung CEC) is enabled in my TV as well, and I can see my receiver appearing in CEC menu. Logical device '5' is my receiver(as mentioned in the question).  I have also mentioned that controlling volume and standby for receiver works fine from TV. Main problem is powering on the receiver from Kodi.